# xcode 4.2.1 - rotation support issue

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios4, device-orientation

I have designed an app to support ios 4.3 and from "Supported Device Orientations" I removed everything and only portrait is active.

The problem is that when I simulate the app in my phone it supports all the orientations and my app looks missed up with the landscape orientations.

how can I force it not to support landscape orientations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view controller call

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
 {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
 }
```

to force it not to rotate in landscape mode. You will also need to make sure all of your parent views have autoresizesSubviews = YES.